# Public final in enum's instance variables

Tags: java, enums, final, public, instance-variables

i would like to know if it's a common accepted practice to give public visibility to final data fields in 'enum' instances, and name them using the CONSTANT_CASE.
I know that it's not strictly correct, but often I use enum instead of final Classes to simplify the code.
An example, I use:

```
public enum PropertyType {

   STRING("string", String.class, "generico"),
   BOOLEAN("boolean", Boolean.class, "vero/falso"),
   NUMBER("number", Double.class, "numerico"),
   INTEGER("integer", Long.class, "intero");

   public final String JSON_TYPE;
   public final Class JAVA_TYPE;
   public final String DESCRIPTION;

   private PropertyType(String jsonType, Class javaType, String description) 
   {
       if (jsonType == null)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("json type can't be null");

       if (javaType == null)
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("java type can't be null");

       this.JSON_TYPE = jsonType;
       this.JAVA_TYPE = javaType;
       this.DESCRIPTION = description;
   }
}
```

instead of

```
public class PropertyType {
    public static final class STRING {
        public static final String JSON_TYPE="string";
        public static final Class JAVA_TYPE=String.class;
        public static final String DESCRIPTION="generico";
    }

    ...
    ...

    private PropertyType() {}
}
```

Both the options let you use syntax like 'PropertyType.STRING.DESCRIPTION', but the first is easier to code and less redundant, plus it's faster to expand while the latter it's long to code with a lot of copy and paste...
Since the purpose of the two it's the same, why require a different naming convention?

Comment: Both examples look wrong to me: naming a class in all capitals (as your `PropertyType.STRING`) is equally a misleading naming convention. What's wrong with `PropertyType.STRING.description()`?

Comment: @DanielPryden good point on class name all in capitals... nothing wrong in 'PropertyType.STRING.description()' itself, but here I use enum to "store and organize" constants, so i'm wandering why not recall the CONSTANT_CASE feel... like 'PropertyType.STRING_DESCRIPTION'... anyway it's not a topic to spend more than 60 seconds on

Answer (score 2):

While this question is primarily opinion-based, I would say the following:

1. upper case field names are adopted to be used only for static constants
2. for this particular case more logical make these object variables private and add conventional getters for them.

Comment: Agree. I would also argue that enum objects should be (deeply) immutable -
 else you're asking for trouble - and by doing so the immutability of their members becomes implicit anyway.

Comment: @Michael And this is the reason why i think it would make no difference to write public instance variables... maybe i'm missing something

Comment: @Schizoping It's just convention. The convention is to use getters over public fields because it's more flexible, and so there doesn't really need to be a style guide for non-static public constants. You can do it and it wouldn't be wrong, but you asked whether it's 'common accepted practice' and it's not.